# Can I make Gradle only pull in needed dependencies?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependency-injection

I am making an Android library that allows the developer to choose which options they would like to use of the library. Each option depends on a different external dependency that is pulled in through Gradle.

My question: Is it possible to make Gradle only pull in dependency A if option B and C are not being used to make the library as small as possible?

I have looked into Dependency Injection but I don't think I understand it enough to determine if this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to minimize transitive dependencies. Take Google Play Services, for example. You can either include all of them with a single dependency, or you can choose, just Maps, for example.

Comment: @cricket_007 Hmm okay, so are saying in the app that is consuming the library I can exclude the unwanted dependencies in the library? I think that might work, thanks!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but you can always exclude groupIds in the Gradle configurations.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yep, thats what I just did and I think its working! I can't believe I didn't think about doing that but thanks again.

Comment: Cool. Sorry about being vague. I'm sure if you answer your own post below, it may help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, thanks to @cricket_007 , instead of trying to do something with the library itself you can just exclude the dependencies you don't want use in the application that is consuming the library's own Gradle.

```
compile ('myAndroidLibrary'){
        exclude group: 'dependency.b'
        exclude group: 'dependency.c'
}
```